# Find all polynomial $f$ such that $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

While working on a functional equation, I came across this question,

Find all polynomial $f$ such that $$f(x)+f(1-x)=1$$

Clearly there is an infinite number of solution. If you set $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_i x^i$$ Then $$2a_0+\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$$ I think this condition is enough for $f$ to satisfy the above functional equation, but can we do better? Can we find $f$ explicitly.

Comment: Set $x=0$ in the functional equation.

Comment: Why only 0? Set any value, say 5.

Comment: Even better, just leave it as $x$, and expand all the terms

Comment: We're trying to get rid of $x$

Comment: You just wrote your equation for $x=0$. You did not "get rid of x".

Comment: What would you do if you leave it as $x$? Match coefficients?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135358/discussion-between-andrei-and-pnt).

Comment: Let $g(x)=f'(x)$ then $g(x)=g(1-x)$ and we can easily characterize those and then recover $f$ by integration

Comment: Setting $a_2=1$ and all others to zero satisfies your then equation but not the functional equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $f(x + 1/2) - 1/2$ is odd.

Comment: I didn't get it?

Comment: Do you know what an odd function is? an odd polynomial?

Comment: $f(-x)=-f(x).$ then what?

Comment: Prove that $Q(x) = f(x+1/2)-1/2$ is an odd polynomial, then deduce $f(x)$ in terms of $Q$, then prove that conversely, every such function is a solution.